# How to export name, latitude and longitude of bus all stops of city from google map?

Tags: google-maps, export-to-excel, latitude-longitude

I want to export all bus stops names with latitude and longitude of specific city from google map or is their any to get these details.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't provide this in the API. There is no way to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way, by hand. http://www.getlatlon.com/ center the bus stops and Bam! you have the long & lat. Not the answer you seek I know but better than nothing, right?